# How do I set a Progress bar for a certain function execution in PyQt GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, progress-bar, pyqt5

I've designed a GUI and after a button click, I am implementing a function named `librosa.effects.hpss()`, which is taking a lot of time for execution. As it is taking a lot of time for execution, I want to see the execution(with start and done indication also) of that function using a progress bar onto the GUI itself. How do I do it?

I've tried these implementations https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/progress-timer-in-python/, but they are all for the `for()` loop implementations, which I don't have any.

This is my code for the function call.

```py
  def hpssop(self):
        self.file = "file.wav"
        self.y, self.sr = librosa.load(self.file)
        self.margin_harms = self.margin_har.value()
        self.margin_pers = self.margin_per.value()
        self.harmonic, self.percussive = librosa.effects.hpss(self.y,
                                                              margin=(self.margin_harms, self.margin_pers))
        librosa.output.write_wav("harmonic.wav", self.harmonic, self.sr)
        librosa.output.write_wav("percussive.wav", self.percussive, self.sr)

    def onseparateclick(self):
        self.hpss.clicked.connect(self.hpssop)
```

This is the GUI but instead of separating status I want progress bar

[image: This is the GUI but instead of separating status I want progress bar]

Comment: is librosa.effects.hpss() returning any value shown the progress or estimating time to finish? I read its documentation there is not something like that. So, I don't think you could do it with this function.

Comment: QProgressbar does not calculate the progress, it only shows the progress. So your task is to calculate it, as indicated by zaher88abd and since I have reviewed `librosa.effects.hpss()` it does not offer anything that indicates a progress so what it asks is impossible. The only thing that the QProgressBar could use is to indicate that there is a task in progress but not show how advanced the process is

Comment: I wouldn't say it is impossible. Maybe you can use a mathematical model to get an approximation of how long it would take to encode the sound. Another option would be to encode a few seconds first, count the time it takes to encode that, then estimate the duration it would take for the whole file. Of course, you would still get an approximation so when reaching the estimated 100% if the process hasn't finished yet you can change the progress bar animation to loop infinitely and the label to display something like: almost there!